# Visual Studio 2019 does not recognize Qt 6.1.2 package names

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I'm new to both Visual Studio and Qt, and am trying to learn how to use them together. I installed Qt 6.1.2 and VS 2019 Professional, and then installed Qt VS Tools and set them up.

To learn, I attempted to recreate the notepad getting-started excercise (https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtwidgets-tutorials-notepad-example.html), but I am having trouble with Visual Studio not being able to identify a lot of package names (or whatever it's called, like <QApplication>). I can recreate the excercise in Qt Creator just fine. I can also see and access the *.h files of Qt in Visual Studio just fine (e.g. #include <QtWidgets/qtextedit.h>).

Examples:

#include <QApplication> //Is accepted in Qt Creator, but not in VS 
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>// Seems to work in Visual Studio, and roughly do the same thing?

#include <QMainWindow> //Is accepted in Qt Creator, but not VS (can't find src file) and I can't find what the suitable equivalent would be

I set up the project as a Qt Widgets Application, and I think Qt VS Tools automatically added the Qt installation include path, path to the .libs files, and names of the .lib files to my project settings (I can see something like $(Qt_INCLUDEPATH_) at the appropriate spots in my project properties).

Is there anything I can change in my project properties to make VS understand the Qt package names or does Qt VS Tools use other names for the packages?